# How can I make webpack search upwards for modules like vanilla Node require?

Tags: webpack, node-modules, yarnpkg

An excerpt from our webpack config file is below.  It seems that webpack is searching for modules only from the directories listed in the 'modules' parameter (ie node_modules and ../../node_modules).  When I remove this line:

```
modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules'), path.resolve(__dirname, './../../node_modules')]
```

It only searches in node_modules.  Due to the way Yarn works, a modules may not be in node_modules of the current directory.  I would like webpack to follow a similar lookup pattern to the rest of node/yarn, which is to first look in node_modules, then ../node_modules, and so on until it finds it.  How can I make sure it does this?  If this is supposed to be the default, is there any other parameter that could be preventing this from happening?

```
module.exports = async (env, options) => {
  const config = {
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
      library: "TypeScriptModule",
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js", ".json"],
      modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules'), path.resolve(__dirname, './../../node_modules')],
    },
...
```

EDIT: Seems that this is due to webpack not following symlinks, is there a way to make it resolve symlinks in node_modules?  Even with       symlinks: true, it doesn't seem to use folders under node_modules which are directory symlinks.